# VBA string function: not returning the value

Tags: excel, vba, string, function, return

I am making an excel sheet with a specific condition that will return a string. **This function worked as a sub-procedure** but when I tried to use it as a function, I keep getting '#VALUE!'. Can someone please help me why this code is not returning the string?

Please see the code below:

```
Function check_input2() As String

Dim range1 As range
Dim range2 As range
Dim row_num As Integer
'Dim col_num As Integer
Dim val As Boolean
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim row_end As Integer
'count = 0
'row_num = range1(1, 1).Row
'col_num = range1(1, 1).Column

a = 1
b = 1
val = True
row_end = 11 + 12

row_num = 11
Set range1 = range("A" & row_num & ":" & "A" & row_end)

For row_num = 11 To row_end
    Set range2 = range("I" & row_num & ":O" & row_num)

    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(range2.Value) = 0 Then
        'nothing has to happen
        val = val And True
        range("Q" & row_num).Value = True
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.Sum(range2.Value) > 0 Then
        If IsEmpty(range1(a, b).Value) = True Then
        val = val And False
        range("Q" & row_num).Value = False '**************************
        ElseIf IsEmpty(range1(a, b).Value) = False Then
        val = val And True
        range("Q" & row_num).Value = True '**************************
        End If
    End If
    a = a + 1
Next

If val = True Then
    'do nothing
    'check_input2 ("hello")--error
    check_input2 = "hello"
    'check_input2 = True
ElseIf val = False Then
    'check_input2 ("Please do not skip the project number!")--error
    check_input2 = "Please do not skip the project number!"
    'check_input2 = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: `val = val And True` is not proper vba.  `val = True`

Comment: @ScottCraner, actually `val = val And True` _is_ proper VBA, although redundant (since it's the same as `val = val`, which is of no use)

Comment: @NaraeGim, both `val = val And False` and `val = val And True` are redundant and should be changed, respectively, to `val = False` and no statement at all. And whichi line is throwing the error?

Comment: It's not redundant...but for sure, I found my error!! Thank you so much!!!!